# Is it necessary to unload the loaded model, or should i just remove all the tags from main forgeViewer tag?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is it a good habit to unload the model, in the current situation I am just removing content from the main forge viewer tag to remove the currently loaded model in order to load another model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the actual HTML markup generated by Forge Viewer is not a good practice.

If you simply want to load another model in the viewer, just call the [loadDocumentNode](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#loaddocumentnode-avdocument-manifestnode-options) method again. By default, it will unload the previous model before loading the new one.